# Create the following Generic IEnumerable in CLI/C++?

Tags: c++-cli

how is it possible to create the following Generic IEnumerable in CLI/C++:

```
IEnumerable<T> Fetch<T>() where T: MyFetch, new() { }
```

I tried some stuff around, but didn't found a solution that looks 'legit' and fits my needs.

**I want the function to be part of a class**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use the ^ hat in the *where* clause.  It names a type, not a handle to the type as you'd use for a variable or parameter declaration.  The T type parameter is already introduced by the *generic* keyword, you don't apply it again to the method name like you'd do in C#.  It should therefore look like this:

```
generic <typename T>
where T: MyFetch, gcnew()
IEnumerable<T>^ Fetch() {
   // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be a generic function in your `ref class`, and would look similar to:

```
generic <typename T>
where T: MyFetch, gcnew()
IEnumerable<T>^ Fetch() 
{
}
```

Comment: "Syntax error: ^", "Unexpected tokens preceding '{' skipping apparent function body" - those two errors appear when copying your generic. "MyFetch" is a ref class and is included. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @phxlol Try without the handle spec : `where T:MyFetch, gcnew()` - does that work?  I updated to correct.